# Ограничить количество выполнений метода класса в секунду

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, парсер, requests

Есть парсер написанный на Python, но имеется одна маленькая проблема, стороннее API может вытерпеть только 7 запросов в секунду, иначе банит по IP. Как мне ограничить количество запросов к API чтобы не получить собственно этот бан?

```
class Parser:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def _make_requests(self):
        ...

    def start_parse(self):
        ...

parse = Parser()
''' Тут должен быть многопоточный вызов функции start_parse '''
```

примерная структура, и хотелось бы сделать ограничение на метод _make_requests потому что все запросы которые выполняются в классе завязаны на нём, чтобы при вызове более 3 start_parse не ловить бан по IP. Если я правильно понимаю концепцию ООП, если ограничить на make_requests для каждого вызова _make_requests будет ограничение, но не понимаю как его сделать

Comment: вот тут был такой же вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1421166/218971

Answer (score 0):

Для решения проблемы можно воспользоваться счетчиком запросов:

```
import time

class Parser:
    __MAX_REQUESTS_COUNT_PER_SECOND = 7
    __requests_count = 0
    __requests_st = 0
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        
    def __increment_requests_count():
        if Parser.__requests_count == 0:
            Parser.__requests_st = time.time()
        elif Parser.__requests_count > Parser.__MAX_REQUESTS_COUNT_PER_SECOND - 1:
            et = time.time()
            if et - Parser.__requests_st < 1:
                #Тут нужно вызывать исключение и ловить его в _make_requests
                raise Exception('У вас слишком много запросов')
            else:
                Parser.__requests_st = time.time()
                Parser.__requests_count = 0
        
        Parser.__requests_count += 1

    def _make_requests(self):
        try:
            Parser.__increment_requests_count()
            ...
        except Exception as err:
            #Вызов исключения / завершение метода
            return

    def start_parse(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Суть понятна. Ну я только тут накостылил немного другое, сделал декоратор
def ratelimit(interval: timedelta) -> Callable:
    """Декоратор для ограничения запросов к функции по времени"""

    release_time = time.time()

    def decorator(func: Callable) -> Callable:
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Any:
            nonlocal release_time

            time.sleep(max(0.0, release_time - time.time()))
            release_time = time.time() + interval.total_seconds()
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator

Comment: Но не знаю как корректно он будет отрабатывать